# How can I add and save customized colours to 'Theme Colors', in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

The 3 colours (used in the 3 tables) in the beneath screenshot don't appear in the Palette. It's too inefficient to retrieve and enter the RGB Colour Code whenever I need them.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done on the **Design** tab (not the **Table Tools** > **Design** tab that appears when the focus is on the table, but the main **Design** tab next to the **Insert** tab).

On the **Design** tab, click **Colors** > **Customize Colors**, and modify the various Accent colors.

Comment: Thanks again. please see https://meta.superuser.com/questions/13075/why-was-my-edit-correcting-a-fact-rejected/13076#13076?

Answer (score 0):

I add a screenshot that depicts [the other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1277593/269574):

[image]