# How can I add and save customized colours to 'Standard Colors', in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I ask about 'Standard', not ['Theme'](https://superuser.com/a/1277593/269574), Colors.

[image]

Comment: I, too, have this problem. this is something that bugs me since the newer versions of word and excel. In the old versions you had a colour grid of I think 32 or so colours that I got used to and used in all my projects and files, and now these are gone, and I still haven't found a way to reproduce them. The Custom Colours also don't help since they tend to get lost when I close the document or switch to a different document. Does anyone know a solution or a workaround here? Basically, I want to have a palette of 32 colours that I can choose myself available in all documents that I create.

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot** change the standard colors.

You can however add colors to the quick access colors (the grid below the color picker) when choosing a custom color (available through the "More Colors..." option). When you use these custom colors, they should appear in the main color dropdown below the standard colors under the caption "Recent Colors".

Answer (score 2):

For `.docx` documents, you can add via themes additional colors to the
Office color-picker as a new section called "Custom Colors" :

[image]

This is how to do that :

- In Word, go to the Design pane
- Click the down-arrow below Themes
- Choose "Save Current Theme..."
- Give  a name and save the `.thmx` file, say as `mytheme.thmx`
- Close Word
- Open the save folder, normally
  `C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes`
- Copy your theme file elsewhere
- Rename the file to `mytheme.thmx.zip`
- Open the file and drill-down to `theme`, `theme` (again)
- Copy the file `theme1.xml` and open it in a text editor
- At the end of the file, just before the tag `</a:theme>`, add a
  `a:custClrLst` tag. Below is the text that produced the "Custom Colors"
  section in my above image :

  ```
  <a:custClrLst>
      <a:custClr name="Dark Blue">
      <a:srgbClr val="1F497D" />
      </a:custClr>
      <a:custClr name="Mint Green">
      <a:srgbClr val="99DB73" />
      </a:custClr>
      <a:custClr name="Girly Pink">
      <a:srgbClr val="FF99FF" />
      </a:custClr>
  </a:custClrLst>
  ```
- Save the `theme1.xml` and replace it in `mytheme.thmx.zip`
- Rename the `mytheme.thmx.zip` back to `mytheme.thmx` and replace it in its
  original folder
- Open Word. If the Custom Colors have not appeared, re-apply the
  template in the Design pane by clicking the down-arrow below Themes
  and re-assigning your template.

This new theme can be assigned to any Office document, not only Word.

References :

- [PPT 2007 custom colors](http://echosvoice.com/powerpoint-2007-custom-colors/)
  This contains a link to a modified THMX file that you can examine.
- [XML Hacking: Custom Colors](http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2015/06/xml-hacking-custom-colors/)
- [XML Hacking: An Introduction](http://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2015/02/xml-hacking-an-introduction/)